# TypeScript - Is there a way to include methods stored in a object into a class?

Tags: typescript, class

This is my code :

```
// outside class methods
function incAge(this: Person) {
    this.age++;
}

function changeNick(this: Person, str : string) {
    this.numberOfNickChanges++;
    this.nick = str;
}
//


interface IPerson {
    incAge: () => void;
    changeNick: (str : string) => void;
    nick : string;
    numberOfNameChanges : number;
}

export class Person implements IPerson {
    public nick: string = "no name";
    public age: number = 0;
    public age: numberOfNickChanges = 0;
    public changeNick: (str : string) => void;
    public incAge: () => void; // Warning : Property 'incAge' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.ts(2564)

    constructor() {
        Object.assign(this, { incAge, changeNick });
        this.incAge(); // Warning : Property 'incAge' is used before being assigned.ts(2565)
        console.log(this.age); // prints 1
    }
}
```

I have these outside class functions `incAge` and `changeNick` that I wanted to incorporate into my class `Person` (IRL functions `incAge` and `changeNick` will be imported from another `.ts` file)

TS warns me that my functions `incAge` and `changeNick` are not defined however, when I create a new instance of this class, it works without a problem when `"ts-node": { "logError": true }` is set in my tsconfig.json.

How can I remove this error and its red squiggly underline (without using `this.incAge = incAge.bind(this);` in the constructor because I would like to include multiple functions that are stored in the same object in the future ?

Answer (score 1):

I have minimised your example, see if this works for you:

Idea is, instead of `Object.assign(this, { incAge })`, you assign value to each function explicitly by `this.incAge = incAge`

```js
// outside class methods
function incAge(this: Person) {
  this.age++
}

interface IPerson {
  incAge: () => void
}

export class Person implements IPerson {
  public age = 0
  public incAge: () => void

  constructor() {
    this.incAge = incAge
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I founded that I must replace several parts of my code :

```
public changeNick!: (str : string) => void;
public incAge!: () => void;
```

and call function like this :

```
this.incAge!();
```